# No selenium test gets executed on Azure DevOps

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, maven-3, cucumber-java

I am trying to run my selenium-cucumber tests on Azure Dev Ops.
I run my tests locally on command prompt or on terminal with

`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@ForgotPassword" -Dbrowser=Firefox`

This works perfectly fine. Now, I want to run the same thing on Azure DevOps. Hence, I have created a pipeline as below

[image]

Maven task is as below

[image]

But, when I run the pipeline, in the logs, it does not detect any test and no test is executed.

```
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    ?
? JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) ?
?                                                                                   ?
? More information at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/environment-variables/      ?
?                                                                                   ?
? Disable this message with one of the following:                                   ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.65 s - in com.mohg.automation.cucumberOptions.TestNGTestRunner
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-04T15:01:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Please show the full pom file...also give more information like JDK you are using? which Maven version you are using etc.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are defining the maven command arguments in Maven Task Goal field. This is the root cause of the issue.

You need to define the argument in the **Option** field.

For example:

[image]

Yaml Sample:

```
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
    goals: test
    options: '-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@ForgotPassword" -Dbrowser=Firefox'
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
```